# Display the number of files uploaded by user using angular

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, count

I am trying to create a web application by which you can add projects and any files relating to it. There is an angular table which displays the project information and I want to include one column which displays the number of files uploaded for each of the projects. The uploaded files are saved in a seperate directory. I have posted some parts of code so that you guys can get an idea about it.

```
<th><button type="button" id="show"># Of Files</button></th>
```

This is the table header for number of files which is a button.

```
<tr ng-repeat="project in allProjects >
<td> {{ ??? }} </td>
```

The above is table data to get the number of files for each project.

```
<input type="file" nv-file-select="" id="myFile" uploader="uploader" multiple />

<button type="button" id="file"> Upload</button>
```

Above is file input with a button to upload the files.

```
$scope.get_files = function(){
    $http.post('core/engine.php?method=route', {'class':'Upload', 'function':'get_project_files', 'data':$scope.project.PROJECT_NAME})
        .success(function(data){
            if (data != 0) $scope.fileList = data;
        })
}
```

Above is the code to upload the files.

```
 static function get_project_files(){
    if(!file_exists(self::$root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::$data)){
        mkdir(self::$root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::$data);
    } else {
        return array_diff(scandir(self::$root . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . self::$data), array('..', '.'));
    }
}
```

This makes a directory and saves the uploaded file in them.

```
$scope.get_count = function(){
    var fi = document.getElementById('file');

 return fi.files.length;
}
```

I have tried to write this part of code and pass it to the table data but it does not work.
Guys any help with this is really appreciated and thanks in advance. Please let me know if you want to know more about this code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get number of files you can simply add a function bind it with change event in the file as follows

```
 <input type="file" multiple (change)="chooseFile($event.target.files)" />
```

Create a choose file function to get the number of the files selected by the user. The following code will do the task

```
 chooseFile(file){

  console.log(file.length)
 }
```

The file is an array containing the total number of the files selected by the user.